# How to insert and retrieve image in dbf file from vb6

Tags: vb6, foxpro

I am writing a code in VB6 to save and retrieve an image in .dbf file, but i don't know what field type to take in dbf file. Can anyone suggest what field should i take in dbf file and what code should i write in VB6 ??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro  Also [FoxPro OleDB driver from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)

Comment: It's possible to use a BLOB type field and write code to write/read it, but I would recommend just storing the image file name in a text field if at all possible. I've done both (long time ago) and if you get even 1 bit wrong you mess up the image. With external files you not only never mess them up, but there's no time overhead getting them into/out of your DB and you can easily view them from the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it in Memo Fields long ago. The code is in foxpro. See:

```
CREATE TABLE Abc.dbf Free (Filename c(50), Store M(4)) &&Create a table with FileName character field
```

*And Store as memo field

1.

```
Append blank &&to add a blank record
APPEND MEMO store from "D:\Shah.Jpg" overwrite 
*This will copy the contents of the file. If Overwrite is ignored, and the memo has some contents,
*The contents of the file will be appended to it, which should be avoided.
REPLACE filename WITH "Shah.Jpg"
*Add as many files as you wish to other records.
Copy memo Store to "SomePhoto.jpg" && will copy to the default folder
*Or 
Copy memo store to "c:\MyPhotos\Shah.JPG" &&You must save or know the extension of the file
```

2.

```
append blank
filedata=FILETOSTR("D:\Shah.JPG")
REPLACE store WITH filedata
STRTOFILE(store,"SomeFileName.JPG")
*OR
STRTOFILE(store,"c:\MyPhotos\SomeFileName.JPG")
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it in Memo Fields long ago. The code is in foxpro. See:

```
CREATE TABLE Abc.dbf Free (Filename c(50), Store M(4))
```

*Create a table with FileName character field

*And Store as memo field 
Method 1:

Append blank &&to add a blank record

```
APPEND MEMO store from "D:\Shah.Jpg" overwrite
```

*This will copy the contents of the file. If Overwrite is ignored, and the memo has some contents, *The contents of the file will be appended to it, which should be avoided.

```
REPLACE filename WITH "Shah.Jpg"
```

*Add as many files as you wish to other records.

```
Copy memo Store to "SomePhoto.jpg"
```

- will copy to the default folder or

  `Copy memo store to "c:\MyPhotos\Shah.JPG"`

*You must save or know the extension of the file

Method 2.

Append blank

```
filedata=FILETOSTR("D:\Shah.JPG") 

REPLACE store WITH filedata 

STRTOFILE(store,"SomeFileName.JPG")
```

*OR

```
STRTOFILE(store,"c:\MyPhotos\SomeFileName.JPG")
```

***It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it In Fox pro 9 it involves saving and retrieving image from MYSQL server.
1. First create table by the name:pictures with two fields image_id (int 10) and image(longBlob).

Now I wrote two function SaveImage RetriveImage"

```
CLOSE DATABASES

DO SaveImage WITH "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New folder (6)\rafay.jpg"
DO RetriveImage WITH "C:\KalimKhan2.jpg"



Function SaveImage
    Parameters ImageName

   && Get image info
   Create Cursor im (pic Blob)
   Appen Blank

  Overwrite`enter code here`
  Append Memo pic From (ImageName) Overwrite

  SQLDisconnect(0)
  nconnect = SQLConnect('TEST_BOX','root')
   If nconnect < 0
       Wait Window 'Connection Failed!' Timeout 1
       Return
   Else
      Wait Window 'Connected. ' Nowait
  Endif
  nresult = SQLExec(nconnect, [INSERT INTO pictures (image) VALUES (?pic) ] )

  If nresult != 1
      Aerror(laErr)
      List Memory Like laErr To File c:\Error
      error1 = .T.
      =Aerror(x)
      Wait Window " Query failed."
  Endif


Return  "good"



Function RetriveImage
    Parameters ImageName

   SQLDisconnect(0)
   nconnect = SQLConnect('TEST_BOX','root')
   If nconnect < 0
       Wait Window 'Connection Failed!' Timeout 1
       Return
   Else
       Wait Window 'Connected. ' Nowait
   Endif

   CursorSetProp("MapBinary",.T.,0)
   nresult = SQLExec(nconnect, [Select * from pictures where image_id = 1 ],"ImageTemp" )
   If nresult != 1
       Aerror(laErr)
       List Memory Like laErr To File c:\Error
       error1 = .T.
       =Aerror(x)
       Wait Window " Query failed."
    Endif

nBytes = Strtofile (ImageTemp.Image, (ImageName))
```